# How to copy a folder in SharePoint?

Tags: migration, folder

Is there any way by which we can copy a folder from one SharePoint site to another SharePoint site?

I know how to copy documents but I am not finding any way to copy a folder which resides in a document library.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best solution is to open the document library in an Explorer window (using WebDav) and move or copy stuff around that way.

You could also use the Site Content and Structure site action (you need to have the publishing feature enabled on your site) and select all the documents in the folder and move them to a new folder. But this tool is not able to move folders as a whole.

Granular backup works at the list level, but won't go down to the level of folders within lists.

Comment: ohh.. You mean there is no SharePoint tool available to copy folder.

Comment: also i ma not finding publishing feature in site features and site collection feature.

Comment: The publishing feature is only available in SharePoint Server 2010 Standard and Enterprise, not in Foundation.

Comment: Presumably dragging and dropping in explorer using WebDav would also lose any metadata too...

Comment: Yep. Metadata will only be kept when you move the data from one place to another with Explorer view

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could make a granular backup of the complete library, then restore that to the destination site and delete everything you don't need once it's restored.

If you want to move the folder to a specific library in the destination site, restore the library to a dummy library in the destination site, then move the folder, then delete the dummy library.

This way all metadata will stay intact (Explorer view does not take into account any metadata associated with the file, it'll just copy the bits).

Answer (score 2):

To copy contents from one site or document library, you need to perform the folowing three actions:

1) Create a document library and corresponding folders in the destination path.

2) Open both source and destination paths in Explorer by hitting the "Open with Explorer" icon that can be found tab the "Library" tab.

3) start copying/moving documents.

[For more information, please visit this link on office.microsoft.com site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/copying-or-moving-sharepoint-document-libraries-HA001154465.aspx)

Hope this helps, Qusay F. Hassan

Comment: I hope he's not still having this problem, two years later ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few 3rd party tools out there which can help especially if you don't have the Publishing infrastructure and want to do useful stuff like save metadata (for all file formats not just Microsoft one), preserve version history or copy stuff outside of your local farm say to SharePoint Online.

One such product (I need to declare a vested interest here) is http://www.kaboodlekonnect.com/renditions.  Apart from being able to copy or archive entire folder structures it has lots of really useful features like being able to automatically sync document copies and create custom reports when documents are archived and it is incredibly easy for end users i.e. its not an admin tool.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this so it's probably answered. But just in case...

How much content do you have in that library? If it's only a little bit, just create the new library and folder by hand, download the docs from the current lib and upload to the new lib using upload multiple.

If it's a lot of content:

1. If you don't have publishing enabled: save the library as a template (be sure Include Content is checked) and create the new library from that template. 
   or
2. If you do have publishing enabled: create the new lib and folder by hand then use the Content and Structure Move items tool as SPDoctor said.